# How to convert a typed definition to a typedstruct?

Tags: types, elixir

### Background

I am moving towards defined data structures in my application, and I find that [TypedStruct](https://github.com/ejpcmac/typed_struct) is quite useful.

### Questions

However, I have recently found a little hickup. I don't know how to convert this definition into a typedstruct:

```
  @type order_info :: %{
    (visible :: String.t()) => boolean,
    (order_type :: String.t()) => String.t(),
    (platform :: String.t()) => String.t(),
    (platinum :: String.t()) => non_neg_integer,
    (user :: String.t()) => %{
      (ingame_name :: String.t()) => String.t(),
      (status :: String.t()) => String.t()
    }
  }
```

My main issue here is the `user` map. Aside from the fact I don't know how to define a typedstruct inside a trypedstruct, how do you guys do this?

1. Do you simply define a map inside the `order_info` typedstruct and ignore the mandatory parameters for the `user` map?
2. Do you create another typedstruct (called `user`) that goes inside the typedsctruct called `order_info`?
3. What is the standard option in Elixir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard Elixir (i.e. without the convenience macros offered by the `typed_struct` package), you would define 2 (or more) structs and types, and reference them from one another, e.g.

```
defmodule User do
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{
    name: String.t(),
    is_active: boolean()
  }

  defstruct name: nil, is_active: false # ... etc.
end

defmodule OrderInfo do
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{
    visible: boolean(),
    platform: String.t(),
    user: User.t()
  }

  # provide a simple list of keys if default values aren't needed
  defstruct [:visible, :platform, :user]
end
```

You'll notice that the `@type` declaration usually names itself `t`: this is only a convention -- i.e. its name is not enforced, but when in Rome...

The goal of `typed_struct` is to reduce boilerplate and you'd end up with something like this:

```
defmodule User do
  use TypedStruct

  typedstruct do
    field :name, String.t()
    field :is_active, boolean(), default: false
    # ... etc...
  end
end

defmodule OrderInfo do
  use TypedStruct
  
  typedstruct do
    field :visible, boolean()
    field :platform, String.t()
    field :user, User.t()
    # ... etc...
  end
end
```

The syntax and result is similar to how `Ecto` schemas are declared.

One tip is that when you move from maps to structs, you have to be especially vigilant about how the keys are referenced: structs always have atom keys, whereas maps may have atoms OR strings, so the syntax may change from `foo["bar"]` to `foo.bar` or `foo[:bar]`.